# How to pass a list of images into the keras train function

Tags: python, image, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I have a list of pgn images. From each image, I extracted a specific object and stored only that object into a separate image. I read original images
into `xTrain` `numpy` array, and extracted objects into `yTrain` `numpy` array:

```
def getFilesList(directory):
    files = os.listdir(directory)
    return map(lambda file: directory + file, files)

def readImagesIntoNumpy(directory):
    filesList = getFilesList(directory)
    images = map(lambda file: plt.imread(file), filesList)
    return np.array(images)

xTrain = readImagesIntoNumpy("./original/")
yTrain = readImagesIntoNumpy("./objects/")
```

I want the model to train how to extract those objects from new images:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(units=64, activation='relu', input_dim=100))
model.add(Dense(units=10, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
          optimizer='sgd',
          metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(xTrain, yTrain, epochs = 5, batch_size = 32)
```

The problem is that the last `model.fit` call throws an error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_17_input
            to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (20, 256, 256, 4)
```

**How to pass a set of images into the keras model for training?**

Answer (score 0):

Your input image shape is (256, 256, 4) and inputs the dense layer shape is 2 as a vector
reshape the data from (256, 256, 1) to (256*256*1,1)

add this layer at the first

```
model.add(Reshape(target_shape = (256*256*256,1), input_shape = (256, 256, 1)))
model.add(Dense(units=64, activation='relu'))
```